# Python Vscode extension - can't change remote jupyter notebook kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I've got the updated Python VSCode extension installed and it works great. I'm able to use the URL with the token to connect to a remote Jupyter notebook. I just cannot seem to figure out how to change the kernel on the remote notebook for use in VSCode.

If I connect to the remote notebook through a web browser, I can see my two environments through the GUI and change kernels.  Is there a similar option in the VSCode extension?

Answer (score 2):

VS Code doesn't currently expose remote kernels in the UI, but we will look into that soon. Can you please log an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues to help us track this request?

Comment: This *does* answer the question. "It's not possible" *is* a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks, i just posted the issue per the link. Any thoughts on if there is some sort of workaround? I tried to to activate the env first on the remote terminal before creating a jupyter session, but that did not seem to work. Sometimes it tries to connect to that kernel and just fails and finds the other one, but once it semmed to connect to that kernel, but the paths were messed up.

Comment: Hey Mike. I'm one of the developers on the team. Right now we don't have a way to enumerate and select from the kernel specs on the remote machine. If this helps with working around this, the way that we currently pick the remote kernel spec is via your current selected interpreter in VS Code. So if you pick a local interpreter with the same python version number as the remote kernel spec that you want you should get that kernel started.

Comment: Hi Ian,
Thanks, that seemed to have worked.  It did give a weird connection error at first saying it could not connect, but then it did connect after all which I verified.  Is it doing some sort of fuzzy match for the env name or does it only try and match an env with the same python version?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply Mike, was on Holiday break. If this helps the strongest match is for a full path match (which would be unlikely on a remote machine) after that it's looking at the python interpreter version number on your local interpreter versus the number on the remote kernel spec. As would be expected most points for major number matches with less points added for minor and build number matches. We don't look at the env name at all.

Comment: @mike-r Would you mind pointing to the github issue you created for this? Has it been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in vscode:

Python: Select interpreter to start Jupyter server

It will allow you to choose the kernel that you want.

Comment: see below for switching to local when remote is already selected.

Answer (score 0):

The command that worked for me in vscode:

Notebook: Select Notebook Kernel

Then, scroll all the way to the bottom, to choose

Connect to Local Kernels will change to local kernel

You can switch between Remote and Local from here.

[image]